# Asset Catalog doesn't open in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I have a xamarin project that it didn't have any problem in visual studio. I don't know why but now I couldn't open the asset catalog to add new images for iOS in visual studio.
Can any body help me please?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Any luck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asset catalogs are supported by Visual Studio but if you need reliable support, manage your asset catalogs in Xamarin Studio and don't edit with Visual Studio.

There are so many issues with Visual Studio ([Xamarin Forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/184585/#Comment_184585)) If you want a stable solution open solution in Visual Studio for Mac (former Xamarin Studio) , edit asset catalogs, save and open solution in Visual Studio to work again.

Works for me over a year stable now, but I wish there was a better solution for this.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and my solution was:

- Exclude `Assets.xcassets` folder from project.
- Uncheck readonly mark from `Assets.xcassets`.
- Restart visual studio

Answer (score 3):

I have had issues with the Asset Catalogs in Visual Studio, the issue for me was two things that both caused the Asset Catalogs not to open:

## 1 Missing/wrong entry in the .csproj file:

In the Contents.json there was specified a file (i.e. image@2x.png) however there was no entry in the .csproj file, this also includes cases where there was an entry in the csproj file but it was the wrong path:

### Solution

Add the following (or edit the appropriate) line to the csproj file:

```
<ImageAsset Include="Resources\Assets.xcassets\image.png.imageset\image@2x.png">
  <Visible>false</Visible>
</ImageAsset>
```

## 2 Slashes/Backslashes (seriously?!?)

In the csproj file for the iOS project, the `ImageAsset` tag for the image was with the wrong kind of slashes (which is probably why it sometimes works with Xamarin Studio on MacOS / Linux)

This will look like this when it does not work:

```
<ImageAsset Include="Resources/Assets.xcassets/image.png.imageset/image@2x.png">
  <Visible>false</Visible>
</ImageAsset>
```

### Solution

Reverse the slashes

```
<ImageAsset Include="Resources\Assets.xcassets\image.png.imageset\image@2x.png">
  <Visible>false</Visible>
</ImageAsset>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by removing duplicates in my .csproj file.

By reading [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2068626/peter)'s answer it helped me resolve this problem which I have been struggling for quite some time.

I had to create other assets files to hold new images since I couldn't reuse/open the assets files in Visual Studio any longer.

For instance, I had this as a duplicate:

```
<ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\LaunchImages.launchimage\Contents.json">
  <Visible>false</Visible>
</ImageAsset>
```

Everything is working as it should now.

Comment: Yes, the csproj file is corrupted. The creation of assets.xcassets through VS IDE will create a png file for each item in contents.json. Some of the images may have the same resolution but for different purpose, so you might have 80.png for 80x80, and 801.png for 80x80 as well but for other item. I hacked contents.json to have both items to use 80.png and remove 801.png. However, apparently VS IDE did not like it and generate corrupted csproj file. So, I deleted Assets under Asset Catalogs, and re-created through IDE. Then things become OK again, since the csproj file is sanitized.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue.
Am using Xamarin Forms in Windows.
My fix:

1. Click 'Show All Files' in top menu bar of Solution Explorer
2. My 'Assets.xcassets' file was grayed out
3. Right-click on that file and selected 'Include in project'
4. Did a Clean, then a re-build, and all is well

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the ios.csproj file got a little bit corrupted though the app is still compiled and running well. Luckily I have the other iOS app with the editor opened normally. Through comparing, I had seen some redundant entries of json files and png file listed in csproj, as siblings of AppDelegate.cs in the same ItemGroup. Removing these redundant entries in csproj and restarting VS 2017 had resolved the problem and the Assets.xcassets editor is opened normally again.

Comment: Likewise.
I found that EVERY entry in the Assets.xcassets Item group had been duplicated twice further down the file.  Each within their own item group.
I don't like having to manually adjust the project file. Removing the dupes sorted it, until it happens again....Painful.
I thiugh that was one of the benefits of IDEs.